# Looking for a less complicated/more efficient way to aggregate data from a table in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, split, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

I have a table with some data that I am trying to organize and be used in different tables. Column 1 is a list of people, column 2 is their services, and column 3 is the employee responsible for that service. Column 1 will sometimes have multiple services and employees assigned to them. This is what the table looks like:

| Client | Service | Employee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client1 | Design | James |
| Client2 | Writing | Frank |
| Client3 | Video | Jessica |
| Client3 | Design | Amy |
| Client2 | Design | Amy |
| Client3 | Writing | Frank |

First I use some `vlookup` and `if` formulas to get each clients' services organized into a separate table, I get this:

| Client | Design | Writing | Video |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client1 | James-Design |  |  |
| Client2 | Amy-Design | Frank-Writing |  |
| Client3 | Amy-Design | Frank-Writing | Jessica-Video |

Next I use `query` to organize each clients' employees/services into columns where the header represents the service they **don't have** so that I can index them into the first table

| Client | Design | Writing | Video |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client1 |  | James-Design | James-Design |
| Client2 | Frank-Writing | Amy-Design | Amy-Design, Frank-Writing |
| Client3 | Frank-Writing, Jessica-Video | Amy-Design, Jessica-Video | Amy-Design, Frank-Writing |

Finally, I use index match to pull the data from that last time into a new column in the first table

| Client | Service | Employee | Other Service/Employee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client1 | Design | James |  |
| Client2 | Writing | Frank | Amy-Design |
| Client3 | Video | Jessica | Amy-Design, Frank-Writing |
| Client3 | Design | Amy | Frank-Writing, Jessica-Video |
| Client2 | Design | Amy | Frank-Writing |
| Client3 | Writing | Frank | Amy-Design, Jessica-Video |

I'm hoping there is a cleaner way of doing all of this. This method works fine, but I end up having multiple tables just to organize the data and the index-match function used in the final step needs to be dragged down the column since I can't use it in an `arrayformula`. There is probably a way to utilize `query` to get this done, but I often get lost in how it works.

tl;dr
Table listing clients, services, and assigned employees. Client3 appears in 3 separate rows, has 3 different services, and 3 assigned employees. Want to add a 4th column to show the other services and employees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use in row 1:

```
={"Other Service/Employee"; INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY({A2:A&"♦", ROW(B2:B), C2:C&"-"&B2:B&","}, 
 "select max(Col3) where Col1 <>'♦' group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,
 9^9)), "♦")), 2, )), C2:C&"-"&B2:B&",", )), ",$", ))}
```

[image]